# Universal xml standard for sales receipts (Point of Sale)

Tags: xml, xsd, standards, point-of-sale

Are there any universal standards (schemas) for storing/exchanging sales receipts in xml?

For Invoices and orders there exist eg. cXML or UBL but I couldn't find any similar standards for sales receipts.

I need to generate the xml from Point of Sale and rather than creating my custom schema I would rather have it compatible with existing standards if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

ARTS provides the IXRetail standard, the tech spec is available at http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/0/5/90582d53-7198-4da0-bf19-f11a181412e2/POSLog%20Spec.pdf .. jump to page 9 and you will find below; there are many more scenarios.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!-- UseCase: Item Purchase from shelf --> 
<POSLog xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/
POSLogRetailTransactionStockView.xsd"> 
<Transaction> 
 <RetailTransaction Version="1.0"> 
 <RetailStoreID>HighStreet</RetailStoreID> 
 <WorkstationID>POS5</WorkstationID> 
 <SequenceNumber>4294967295</SequenceNumber> 
 <BusinessDayDate>2001-08-13</BusinessDayDate> 
 <BeginDateTime>2001-08-13T09:03:00</BeginDateTime> 
 <LineItem> 
 <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber> 
 <Sale ItemType="Stock"> 
 <POSIdentity> 
 <POSItemID>01234567890123</POSItemID> 
 </POSIdentity> 
 <ActualSalesUnitPrice>1.63</ActualSalesUnitPrice> 
 <ExtendedAmount>4.89</ExtendedAmount> 
 <Quantity>3</Quantity> 
 </Sale> 
 </LineItem> 
 <LineItem> 
 <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber> 
 <Tender TenderID=”Cash” TypeCode=”Sale”> 
 <Amount>4.89</Amount> 
 </Tender> 
 </LineItem> 
<Total TotalType="TransactionGrandAmount"> 
 <Amount>4.89</Amount> 
 </Total> 
 </RetailTransaction> 
 </Transaction> 
</POSLog>
```

Answer (score 0):

For existing Point of Sale (POS) XML work, check out:

- [Point Of Sale eXtended Markup Language (POSXML)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSXML)
- XML-POS in [UnifiedPOS](http://www.nrf-arts.org/content/unifiedpos)